# Google Assistant custom payload with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to add telephone link in the Link out suggestions of google assistant, but it don't allow me to do it as its saying only http/https urls.

[image]

Is there any custom payload which will allow me to do it?
If yes please provide me some links which might be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, link out suggestions can only be HTTP or HTTPS.

> If your suggestion chip links out to an external website (using
>   addSuggestionLink or linkOutSuggestion) the destination site must be
>   verified and use the same protocol (http vs https) as the URL.

(Source: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip)